# Scroll to top load more

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, swift2, infinite-scroll

I've been searching a lot, but I don't find a clear way to create an **Scroll to top load more, or infinite scroll**, just like you see on chats, e.g whatsapp.
I was trying using **scrollViewDidScroll** method, load data again based on current page

```
    if self.tableView.contentOffset.y == 0 {
        loadData(++currentPage, itemsPerPage: pageSize)
    }
```

But the way to handle new data and scroll position it's a little weird for me, so the main problem is adding content in an efficient way, at the top of my UITableView

//Update

In ScrollViewDidScroll method:

After contentOffset.y reaches 0 position, I'm trying to prepend new messages, since it must appear at top of UITableView, so inserting messages at index 0 is the only way I find to do this. But there is one thing, after pulling new data, and reloading UITableView, scroll position remains displaying at visible screen, last pulled message on top. This is not the expected behaviour, look this slack channel pic

[image]

when scroll reached proper offset, new data was pulled, and screen it's on the same message, but looks now the scroll position

so, I think reloading entire table view in this case is the problem, but how could you pull the data in the tableView properly to get this expected scroll behaviour?

e.g in whatsapp it's the same

Comment: I've never worked on this problem before. Sounds fun. What exactly is not working for you? Are you not able to detect when the user scrolls to the top or are you not able to add more content to the top of your view?

Comment: So the main problem is adding content in an efficient way, at the top of my UITableView

Comment: Did you figured it out? I'm dealing with a similar issue..

Answer (score -3):

I recommend make prefetching in UITableView delegate's method

```
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, willDisplayCell cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

      //your code ()
          if indexPath.row == datasource.count - 3 {
            loadMore()
         }   
     }
```

This allows you to avoid weird behaviour of scroll view.

Comment: But this will work for a scroll to bottom load more, reaching close last cell, I'm trying to do this at scroll to top, just like whatsapp chats

Comment: Sorry, missed this.yes, then you really will have to rely on tableView's offset. You can subscribe on offset's changes with KVO

Comment: subscribe on offset's changes is no problem, since I'm using UITableView, the tricky part it's how to handle the data, and add at top

Comment: @Steve any soilution you got ? if yes just post here please